# creating a pivot query using values from another table rather writing a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a pivot query below that doesn't work because it doesn't like the

> for Des in (select....

part. Normally where the select is I would write the column names dynamically. However I was wondering if there was a way to run this pivot without having to write the query dynamically and instead use the values from my table tblReg?

```
 select * from
 (
      select Id, Des, Val from tblData
      where Date = '2019-06-20' and Des in (select IndVar from tblReg where)
 )source pivot(max(Val) for Des in (select QUOTENAME (IndVar) from tblReg)) 
 as pvt
```

Comment: *" However I was wondering if there was a way to run this pivot without having to write the query dynamically and instead use the values from my table tblReg"* No; you have to define your columns. Just like you can't use a variable to replace the name of a obkect, you can reference a table to replace a list of columns in a `PIVOT`.

Comment: @Larnu ah ok thanks for that. Guessing the answer below with [col1], [col2] in their answer has misunderstood the question

Comment: @mHelpMe . . . To do what you want, you need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

use value of Des as a column name

```
select * from
     (
          select Id, Des, Val from tblData
          where Date = '2019-06-20' and Des in (select IndVar from tblReg where)
     )source pivot(max(Val) for Des in ([col1],[col2],[col3]....)) 
     as pvt
```

Comment: sorry not sure I fully understand. use value name as a column?

Comment: @mHelpMe use value of Des as a column name inside in

Comment: yes I can do that if I write a dynamic query but I wanted to know whether it was possible to use a select query for the Des in () part so I don't have to write a dyanmic query